# Cannot create bucket

Tags: autodesk-forge

I'm trying to create a bucket with the [POST buckets](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/data/v2/reference/http/buckets-POST/) endpoint. However, I cannot seem to do this: When attempting to do so with a Three-legged token, I receive the error:

> "Only 2 legged service tokens are allowed to access this api."

But when I use a two-legged token (with the same scopes):

> "Token does not have the privilege for this request."

What am I doing wrong? I'm using NodeJS with the Request library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to check your Token have the correct scopes in this case you need bucket:create as part of your token scopes.

More about it here. https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/oauth/v2/developers_guide/scopes/

Comment: Thank you, but my token does have the required bucket:create scope, along with data:read, data:write, bucket:read and viewables:read

Comment: Can you post the snippet of code you are using to create the bucket? We haven't heard of any problems with the POST for bucket creation. Also another place you can check is our Tutorial material since we have a server side function in Node to create buckets. Check out this section http://learnforge.autodesk.io/#/datamanagement/oss/nodejs

Comment: Now I feel dumb. I had something along the lines of `scopes: isThreeLeg?formatScopes(myScopes):"data:read"`in my token request and this didn't reflect in the data structure I built around the token. So yes, my token did actually lack the required scope.